# Solr - Create List Type Field

Tags: solr

How do I create a solr field that stores a list of ints? I thought that this should be doable but can not find any documents that describe how. I checked the solr field type list but it appears that ListType is not supported as default.  Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Simply make sure the field has multiValued="true", and then you can add as many values as you want to the field.

An example of adding multiple values in JSON format:

```
$ URL=http://localhost:8983/solr/update/json
$ curl $URL -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '
[
  {
    "id" : "MyTestDocument",
    "my_int_field" : [10, 100, 5, 25, 59]
  }
]'
```